# Interpreting viterbi decoding and posterior probabilities

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

I am wondering why the last state of the predicted probabilities does not match the viterbi decoding sequence.

Consider this MWE:

```
library(HMM)
trans_probs <- c(0.25 , 0.5  , 0.025, 0.2  , 0.025, 0.25 , 0.15 , 0.075, 0.5  ,
                 0.025, 0.05 , 0.025, 0.05 , 0.85 , 0.025, 0.025, 0.075, 0.15 ,
                 0.125, 0.625, 0.05 , 0.075, 0.475, 0.025, 0.375)
transProbs <- matrix(data=trans_probs, nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)


emission_probs <- c(0.6  , 0.175, 0.175, 0.05 , 0.05 , 0.6  , 0.175, 0.175, 0.05 ,
                    0.175, 0.6  , 0.175, 0.05 , 0.175, 0.175, 0.6  , 0.6  , 0.05 ,
                    0.175, 0.175)
emissionProbs <- matrix(data=emission_probs, nrow=5, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

observation <- c('0', '2', '1', '0', '2', '1', '3')

d_init <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)

hmm <- initHMM(States = c('0', '1', '2', '3', '4'), # List of states
               Symbols = c('0', '1', '2', '3'), # List of potential observations
               startProbs = d_init, # Initial probabilities
               transProbs = transProbs, # Transition matrix
               emissionProbs = emissionProbs) # Emission matrix
```

```
viterbi(hmm, observation)
# "4" "2" "3" "4" "2" "3" "4"
```

```
posterior(hmm, observation)
      index
states          1          2          3          4          5          6          7
     0 0.29617487 0.11420953 0.04867024 0.19014791 0.12761431 0.05713045 0.01679575
     1 0.02431431 0.17779530 0.16953596 0.01685586 0.12137835 0.28633013 0.07110010
     2 0.01700985 0.61010230 0.02643983 0.01053570 0.51826439 0.20811925 0.07377565
     3 0.02427890 0.04835995 0.72334261 0.04223564 0.04093185 0.43001382 0.61623302
     4 0.63822207 0.04953292 0.03201137 0.74022489 0.19181110 0.01840636 0.22209549
```

Notice the last observation, 7, departs from the pattern of the highest posterior probability matching the viterbi decoding selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the inference (estimation of the hidden states) made by the `viterbi` function optimizes another criterion than the `posterior` function.

With $\pmb{X}$ the vector of hidden random variables and $\pmb{Y}$ the vector of observed random variables, `viterbi` gives you the Maximum A Posteriori (MAP) estimate defined by:

$$
\hat{\pmb{x}}^{MAP} = \mathrm{argmax}_{\pmb{x}}p(\pmb{X}=\pmb{x}|\pmb{Y}=\pmb{y}).
$$

On the other hand, `posterior` gives you the estimate of each marginal probability. If you take locally the argument maximum of this posterior probabilities you will find differences with the MAP estimate. The corresponding sequence you have infered is sometimes called marginal MAP or Maximum Posterior Mode (MPM). It is then defined by, $\forall n\in\{1,\dots,N\}$:

$$
\hat{x}_n^{MPM}=\mathrm{argmax}_{x_n}p(X_n=x_n|\pmb{Y}=\pmb{y}).
$$

If you want to learn more, you can search for elements on *Bayesian decision theory*.